# Cosmosdb : "message":"Syntax error, invalid numeric value token '4d5f'." error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query some information from the document db, it used to work earlier when we have id field , I recently replaced with Guid field and when we run the following query it throws the error as follows

**Code:**

```
  queryString = string.Format(
                        "SELECT f.keys.Timestamp,f.keys.selectedFieldId FROM {0} f WHERE f.logevent = '{1}' AND f._ts > {2} AND f._ts <= {3}",
                        DocumentDbRepository.DatabaseId, Enums.Events.ApplicationAuthenticationSuccess, refUnixTime,
                        currentUnixTime);
```

**ERROR:**

```
"message":"Syntax error, invalid numeric value token '4d5f'."
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568581/how-to-select-from-collection-with-guid-id?rq=1

Comment: You don't need to have DatabaseId / {0} in the query.  Also I hope the refUnixTime and currentUnixTime time emit proper epoch data

Comment: @AravinthKannan it does not work, throws same errorr

Comment: Try to capture the network trace when executing your query via the [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Also, you could update your `queryString` sample and execute it on Azure Portal to narrow this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the replacement value of {0} in the FROM clause, then it has to conform to a valid identifier (i.e. starts with an alphabetic character or underscore).
Anyways, you really don't need to specify the database Id here, any identifier will do since the collection is always the one you're connected to. In other words, you could write the query as 'SELECT ... FROM f WHERE ...)

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar issue while using Cosmos DB Java API. It got resolved using SqlQuerySpec APIs

Use DocumentClient.queryDocuments(String collectionLink, SqlQuerySpec querySpec,FeedOptions  options)

@param1 and @param2 are placeholder in query string and will be replaced by id and user when we set to SqlParameter. When SqlParameterCollection and query are passed to SQLQuerySpec , it replace placeholder values from query string with corresponding value againt key userd in SqlParameterCollection.

```
//Create SQLQuerySpec instance as below


String query = "SELECT * FROM mycollections m WHERE w.id =@param1 and w.user 
=@param2";
SqlParameterCollection col = new SqlParameterCollection();
SqlParameter sqlParameter1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", id);
SqlParameter sqlParameter2 = new SqlParameter("@param1", user);
col.add(sqlParameter1);
col.add(sqlParameter2);
SQLQuerySpec sqlspec = new SQLQuerySpec(query,col);
FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions()
options.setEnableCrossPartitionKey(true);
List<Documents> results = documentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink, 
sqlSpec,options).getQueryIterable().toList()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.